# PHP List and index all files and directories with links to parent/subdirectories that also index those contents

Tags: php, file, directory, indexing

So I have a homework assignment where I have to index a specific directory to list all files and links of all subdirectories/parent directories.  After the link to the subdirectory or parent directory is clicked, it opens up that directory, indexing all files and subdirectories / parent directories within that directory also.  It's also supposed to show what path you are currently in at the top.  So far, this is all I have but I am not sure how I'm supposed to index the directories that you click on.

```
$d = dir("c:/web");
echo "Path: " . $d->path . "\n";
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
   echo "<li><a href='{$entry}'>{$entry}</a></li>";
}
$d->close();
```

It isn't much, but I need to separate the directories and the files, so only the directories have links to them.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

bool is_dir ( string $filename ) - Tells whether the given filename is a directory.

for the parent directory:

```
$currentDirectory = 'c:/web';
$parentDirectory = realpath($currentDirectory . '/../');
```

Comment: How am I supposed to index the parent or sub directories the same way the current directory is indexed though?

Comment: @DannyYun Can you define what you mean by indexing?

Comment: @DannyYun you can also check out http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php which may also help you reach your final solution.

Comment: By indexing I mean, listing all the files/directories of each sub directory or parent directories

Comment: ok then definately check out the link I mentioned above, that will read the directory and allow you to put it into an array.  From there you can output the array as you have done in your example above.  Using is_dir will allow you to determine if you want to link it or not.